# How to trigger a CLIENT_ERROR or SERVER_ERROR with entity?

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm trying to debug an web application running on Glassfish and I want to cause the server to return a CLIENT_ERROR or SERVER_ERROR.

The returned `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` to the calling server should include an entity. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a filter and make it return the required Response:

javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter

```
@Provider
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext req) throws IOException {
        if (req.getUriInfo().getPath().toLowerCase().contains("pathToMatch")) {
            final Response newResp = Response.status(500).entity("<test>test</test>").type(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).build();
            req.abortWith(newResp);
        }
    }
}
```